# Making mouse movements humanlike (using an arc rather than a straight line to the destination)

Tags: java, mouse, bezier, awtrobot

I am making and auto clicker using java.awt.Robot. One of the concerns i have however is the movements aren't very humanlike. Can anyone suggest some changes to my code to make it more human like? Right now it just moves in a straight line.

```
/**
 * 
 * @param robot The java.awt.Robot being utilized
 * @param sx The start x position of the mouse
 * @param sy The start y potition of the mouse
 * @param ex The end x position of the mouse
 * @param ey The end y position of the mouse
 * @param speed The speed at which to travel
 */
public void moveMouse(Robot robot, int sx, int sy, int ex, int ey, int speed){
    for (int i=0; i<100; i++){  
        int mov_x = ((ex * i)/100) + (sx*(100-i)/100);
        int mov_y = ((ey * i)/100) + (sy*(100-i)/100);
        robot.mouseMove(mov_x,mov_y);
        robot.delay(speed);
    }

}
```

**Update:**
I decided to go with an algorithm that makes use of [Bézier Curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve). It's been a very long time since I implemented the change, but I wanted to post it here just in case people would find it useful in the future. Here is what I ended up with:

```
public class MouseEvent{
    public int getMouseX(){
        return MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x;
    }

    public int getMouseY(){
        return MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y;
    }

    public void moveMouse(int speed, int destX, int destY, int ranX, int ranY){
        Mouse.moveMouse(new Robot(), new Point(getMouseX(),getMouseY()), new Point(destX, destY), speed, ranX, ranY);
    }
}

public class Mouse {
    public static void moveMouse(Robot robot, Point s, Point e, int speed, int ranX, int ranY){
        if(Math.abs(e.x-s.x) <= ranX && Math.abs(e.y-s.y) <= ranY)
            return;

        Point[] cooardList;
        double t;    //the time interval
        double k = .025;
        cooardList = new Point[4];

        //set the beginning and end points
        cooardList[0] = s;
        cooardList[3] = new Point(e.x+random(-ranX,ranX),e.y+(random(-ranY,ranY)));

        int xout = (int)(Math.abs(e.x - s.x) /10);
        int yout = (int)(Math.abs(e.y - s.y) /10);

        int x=0,y=0;

        x = s.x < e.x 
            ? s.x + ((xout > 0) ? random(1,xout) : 1)
            : s.x - ((xout > 0) ? random(1,xout) : 1);
        y = s.y < e.y 
            ? s.y + ((yout > 0) ? random(1,yout) : 1)
            : s.y - ((yout > 0) ? random(1,yout) : 1);
        cooardList[1] = new Point(x,y);

        x = e.x < s.x 
            ? e.x + ((xout > 0) ? random(1,xout) : 1)
            : e.x - ((xout > 0) ? random(1,xout) : 1);
        y = e.y < s.y 
            ?  e.y + ((yout > 0) ? random(1,yout) : 1)
            : e.y - ((yout > 0) ? random(1,yout) : 1);
        cooardList[2] = new Point(x,y);

        double px = 0,py = 0;
        for(t=k;t<=1+k;t+=k){
            //use Berstein polynomials
            px=(cooardList[0].x+t*(-cooardList[0].x*3+t*(3*cooardList[0].x-
                cooardList[0].x*t)))+t*(3*cooardList[1].x+t*(-6*cooardList[1].x+
                cooardList[1].x*3*t))+t*t*(cooardList[2].x*3-cooardList[2].x*3*t)+
                cooardList[3].x*t*t*t;
            py=(cooardList[0].y+t*(-cooardList[0].y*3+t*(3*cooardList[0].y-
                cooardList[0].y*t)))+t*(3*cooardList[1].y+t*(-6*cooardList[1].y+
                cooardList[1].y*3*t))+t*t*(cooardList[2].y*3-cooardList[2].y*3*t)+
                cooardList[3].y*t*t*t;
            robot.mouseMove((int)px, (int)py);
            robot.delay(random(speed,speed*2));
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: What does "humanlike" supposed to mean?

Comment: Not move exactly in a straight line, arc a couple of pixels here and there maybe.

Comment: Then generate random number and vary the straight line using that number. Then use robot class.

Comment: But i dont want to randomly generate a number because then the mouse movement would be kind of jaggedy, think about it, mouse movements are for the most part smooth arcs

Comment: The update is nice, but it only does a curve if the point is highly randomized. If you want a precise destination (or within 10 pixels), its pretty much a straight line still. I considered calling that method twice but it doesnt feel right. I feel like I will throw in some randomized calls. Few where it calls the method 2-3 times (first call being highly randomized destination, while the last call being precise) that tries to "correct" the destination, some where it goes straight to the destination etc, I think thats more humanlike.

Comment: After playing around with your code abit more, I changed the  int xout = (int)(Math.abs(e.x - s.x) /10);
        int yout = (int)(Math.abs(e.y - s.y) /10); to /2 and it got what I've been looking for personally. https://i.imgur.com/PITMbH3.png that was with precision of 5
moveMouse0(7,700,700,5,5);

Answer (score 2):

```
 public void moveMouse(int sx, int sy, int ex, int ey, int speed) throws AWTException {
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        int a = 10;
        boolean flag = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            int mov_x = ((ex * i) / 100) + (sx * (100 - i) / 100);
            int mov_y = ((ey * i) / 100) + (sy * (100 - i) / 100);
            if (flag == true) {
                robot.mouseMove(mov_x + a, mov_y); // adds 10 to X-axis
                flag = false;
            } else {
                robot.mouseMove(mov_x - 2 * a, mov_y); // subtracts 20 to X-axis
                flag = true;
            }
            robot.delay(speed);
        }
    }
```

Just manipulated your code. This moves the mouse in straight path in X-direction. You can achieve what you want from here. Just get the ideas. You can move any way you want if you can manipulate `mov_x` and `mov_y` .

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I dont see anything in what you added that ensures the end point will be the target destination.. Also, all this does is zig-zag all over the place, even if you change a = 1, the mouse still shakes rapidly, no where close to being a smooth arc

Comment: What did you pass on moveMouse() ? I tried moveMouse(30,30,30,500,100). and i suppose arc means somewhat like part of circle, which is NOT humanlike.

Comment: By the way, if you want to generate circle, line or any type of curve movement with some randomness(humanlike in your term), first you have to know Circle, line or curve drawing algorithms then manipulate it to generate randomness. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6641977/how-to-create-a-curve-between-2-points-in-2d-and-get-back-points-that-makes-that

Comment: No, I dont mean a circle, and when i say arc i mean stray off from a straight line by like 1-4 pixels or so, not huge arks

Comment: When moveMouse(30,30,30,500,100) called, it exactly does what you are saying you want.

Comment: try doing running it where the start is only like 10-20 pixels from the destination

Comment: Are you supposed to get exact code you want? That's just a logic how to do it. You can edit the code and make it work for 10-20 pixels. Now, you sound like you don't understand even the code you have posted. Good luck.

Comment: This is terrible code. All it does is zigzag. This is a visual output: https://i.imgur.com/1wuxKuq.png with inputs moveMouse(200,200, 500,500,50); I dont see how that is remotely human like, even with the adjusted values, no human zigzags their mouse like this..

Answer (score 1):

You could use Catmull-Rom method. Generate random controlpoints somewhere around the endpoints and maybe where the straight line would be, asking for coordinates on every step moving from start to end (parameter t, from zero to one).

See demo applets and source: http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~lambert/splines/