# Which random() library is this person using that takes 2 arguments?

Tags: java

I am trying to understand the code below. but I can't seem to make it run. The compile complains that the random() expects 0 arguments. Did the guy make his own random function?

[Making mouse movements humanlike (using an arc rather than a straight line to the destination)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8534189/making-mouse-movements-humanlike-using-an-arc-rather-than-a-straight-line-to-th?rq=1)

Comment: It's a method that the author them self has created and has not shown to us.

Comment: `java.util.Random` doesn't have a `random(..)` nor `random()` method on it.  Definitely one of their own creation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking a wild stab, but I'm 99% sure it's just:

```
private static final Random rnd = new Random();

public static int random(int min, int max) {
   return rnd.nextInt(max - min) + min;
}
```

or possibly:

```
private static final Random rnd = new Random();

public static int random(int min, int max) {
   return rnd.nextInt(max + 1 - min) + min;
}
```

The second version is 'inclusive', as in `random(1,2)` will return a one 50% of the time and a two 50% of the time,  whereas the first one is 'exclusive', as in `random(1,2)` will return a one 100% of the time.